# How do I use @ViewChild with an external ng-template (Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-template, ngtemplateoutlet

**THE PROBLEM**

So I have two Angular components, a parent and a child. The parent passes a custom template to the child component, which then hydrates the template with its own data using ngTemplateOutlet.

This works well for the most part. Unfortunately, I run into issues when trying to access the DOM elements of this parent template from the child.

If I try to access `<div #container></div>` from the default child template using `@ViewChild('container',{static: false})`, it gets the element without issue. When I do the same using the custom template passed in by app.component, I get the error "cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined".

What else do I have to do to access the DOM of my template?

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfavg2)

**App.Component (Parent)**

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

```html
<child [customTemplate]="parentTemplate"></child>

<ng-template #parentTemplate let-context="context">

    <div #container>HELLO FROM CONTAINER</div>
    <button (click)="context.toggleShow()">Toggle Display</button>
    <div *ngIf="context.canShow">Container contains the text: {{context.getContainerText()}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

**child.component (Child)**

```js
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() public customTemplate!: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild("container", { static: false })
  public readonly containerRef!: ElementRef;

  templateContext = { context: this };
  canShow: boolean = false;
  

  toggleShow() {
    this.canShow = !this.canShow;
  }
  getContainerText() {
    return this.containerRef.nativeElement.textContent;
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplate || defaultTemplate; context: templateContext">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #defaultTemplate>
    <div #container>GOODBYE FROM CONTAINER</div>
    <button (click)="toggleShow()">Toggle Display</button>
    <div *ngIf="canShow">Container contains the text: {{getContainerText()}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

**MY QUESTION**

How do I use @ViewChild to access this div from an outside template that updates with any changes in the DOM? (Note: Removing the *ngIf is NOT an option for this project)

What's causing this? Are there any lifecycle methods that I can use to remedy this issue?

**MY HUNCH**
I'm guessing that ViewChild is being called BEFORE the DOM updates with its new template and I need to setup a listener for DOM changes. I tried this and failed so I'd really appreciate some wisdom on how best to proceed. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
This solution needs to properly display `<div #container></div>` regardless of whether you're passing in a custom template or using the default one.

Answer (score 5):

`ViewChild` doesn't seem to pick up a rendered template - probably because it's not part of the components template initially. It's not a timing or lifecycle issue, it's just never available as a `ViewChild`

An approach that does work is to pass in the template as content to the child component, and access it using `ContentChildren`. You subscribe to the `ContentChildren` `QueryList` for `changes`, which will update when the DOM element becomes rendered

You can then access the `nativeElement` (the `div`). If you wanted you could add listeners here to the DOM element, and trigger `cd.detectChanges` afterwards, but that would be a bit unusual. It would probably be better to handle DOM changes in the parent element, and pass the required values down to the child using regular `@Input` on the child

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <child>
      <ng-template #parentTemplate let-context="context">
        <div #container>Parent Template</div>
      </ng-template>
    </child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: "child",
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplate"> </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild("parentTemplate")
  customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChildren("container")
  containerList: QueryList<HTMLElement>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.containerList.changes.subscribe(list => {
      console.log(list.first.nativeElement.innerText);
      // prints 'Parent Template'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. It works with the custom template but it breaks the default child template now. The solution needs to work regardless of whether a custom template is passed or not. Here's my implementation of your solution (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdakal)